# IOS - Print image to Phomemo M02 Mini Bluetooth Thermal Printer using CoreBluetooth in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, printing, uikit, swift5, core-bluetooth

I have a [Phomemo M02 Mini Bluetooth Thermal Printer](https://phomemo.com/products/phomemo-m02-bluetooth-thermal-paper-pocket-printer-black) that I want to print the below image to from my IOS app:

[image]

In my app the above image gets taken from a UIView. I've tried converting that image into data and then sending that data to the printer through bluetooth using the CoreBluetooth Framework, but the printer just printed no image and wouldn't stop unrolling it's paper unless I unpaired my app from the device. With that said, does anyone know how to properly send image data, or just an image, to a Phomemo M02 Mini Bluetooth Thermal Printer for it to print it, and for the printer to actually stop unrolling it's paper after drawing the image? That would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Heres my code:

*The code for turning my UIView into an image:*

```
extension UIView {
    func captureShot () -> UIImage {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, self.layer.contentsScale)
        drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return ((image != nil) ? image! : UIImage())
    }
}
```

*The code for sending the image data to the printer:*

```
let imageData = printView.captureShot().jpegData(compressionQuality: 100)
if (imageData != nil) {
   imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
   print("image size: \(UIImage(data: imageData!)!.size)")
   globalPeripheral.writeValue(imageData!, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
}
```

Comment: You need to read the manual for the device and see how you need to format the data that you send to it. It might accept PCL or ESC/POS or some other format.  It is unlikely that you can just send it a jpeg.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/vivier/phomemo-tools) indicates that it uses Epson ESC/POS

Comment: do you have solution for this one? i'm also trying with this printer, they slice data in to smaller pieces and send it..

Comment: @QuangHà I have used [this swift formatted ESC/POS printer framework](https://github.com/KevinGong2013/Printer) after I got help from Paulw11 who found out that the Phomemo M02 printer used ESC/POS. If you’re planning on sending images to your phomemo printer, make sure each image’s width and height are multiples of 8 (image width/8 -> whole number, image height/8 -> whole number).

Comment: @Paulw11 I apologize for this late reply. Thank you for your help with finding out that the printer used ESC/POS as the help was beneficial :)

Comment: thank you very much for so accurate info @techyCode1 Really appreciate your knowledge.