# How can I get Phomemo D30 bluetooth label printer working in swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, printing, bluetooth

I have recently purchased a Phomemo D30 bluetooth label printer (thermal) to have it print from my own developed iOS app (iOS 15+).

I am using below printer driver for ESC/POS which I have understood the printer is using:

https://github.com/KevinGong2013/Printer

However, I can't get it to work at all. It compiles and runs fine, but when i click "Print", nothing is printed (only the dummyPrinter.print(ticket) is printing into console).

I'm using below code to simply print "1234" on a label:

```
    private let bluetoothPrinterManager = BluetoothPrinterManager()
    private let dummyPrinter = DummyPrinter()
    
    func printNow() {
        let ticket = Ticket(
            .plainText("1234")
        )
        
        // connect your pirnter&print ticket.
        if bluetoothPrinterManager.canPrint {
            print("canprint = yes")
            bluetoothPrinterManager.print(ticket)
        }
        else {
            print("can't print")
        }
        dummyPrinter.print(ticket)
    }
```

And using this to call the printNow method:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Spacer()
            Button("Print", action: {
                printNow()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But the "if bluetoothPrinterManager.canPrint {" always returns false, so nothing is printed. But I can't figure out where the printer is actually defined/selected. Such example is not included in the Printer driver description. I have no clue where to go from here.

I have looked at below question as well (M02 model and not D30) and it seems that it's possible to get it working somehow:

[IOS - Print image to Phomemo M02 Mini Bluetooth Thermal Printer using CoreBluetooth in Swift 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911422/ios-print-image-to-phomemo-m02-mini-bluetooth-thermal-printer-using-coreblueto)

I have also contacted Phomemo directly, as it seems that there is a specific SDK to be used, but they are not replying to my requests.

Hope anybody that have got it working can help me.

Comment: That library isn't well documented. You need to scan for available Bluetooth printers and show a list for the user to select the printer they want to use. The library does seem to provide a [table view controller](https://github.com/KevinGong2013/Printer/blob/refactor/Sources/Printer/Hardware/Bluetooth/BluetoothPrinterSelectTableViewController.swift) to help with this, but you may want to create your own. It also depends on the Bluetooth service advertised by the printer being the one that is included in the Bluetooth manager class